# Sphinx does not find any source

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to generate a documentation for the python part of my project with sphinx. I want to do it in gitlab-ci file, but for now I can't even make it work locally.

Project structure:

```
dev/
 src/
   other-src/
   python-api/
      src/
         conf.py
         index.rst
         mymodule/
           submodule1/
             some python files
           submodule2/
             some python files
           submodule3/
             some python files
           some python files
doc/
  source/
  build/
public/
```

I want to generate the documentation for all python files in dev/src/python/src/mymodule. However, all of my try lead to an empty documentation and I guess I've misunderstood something.

I tried to follow the official quick-start: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html

```
user@host:~/test$ cd doc/
user@host:~/test/doc$ sphinx-quickstart 
Bienvenue dans le kit de démarrage rapide de Sphinx 3.2.1.

Please enter values for the following settings (just press Enter to
accept a default value, if one is given in brackets).

Selected root path: .

You have two options for placing the build directory for Sphinx output.
Either, you use a directory "_build" within the root path, or you separate
"source" and "build" directories within the root path.
> Séparer les répertoires build et source (y/n) [n]: y

The project name will occur in several places in the built documentation.
> Nom du projet: *******
> Nom(s) de l'auteur: *********
> version du projet []: ***

If the documents are to be written in a language other than English,
you can select a language here by its language code. Sphinx will then
translate text that it generates into that language.

For a list of supported codes, see
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-language.
> Langue du projet [en]: en

Fichier en cours de création /test/doc/source/conf.py.
Fichier en cours de création /test/doc/source/index.rst.
Fichier en cours de création /test/doc/Makefile.
Fichier en cours de création /test/doc/make.bat.

Terminé : la structure initiale a été créée.

You should now populate your master file /test/doc/source/index.rst and create other documentation
source files. Use the Makefile to build the docs, like so:
   make builder
where "builder" is one of the supported builders, e.g. html, latex or linkcheck.
user@host:~/test/doc$
```

As this step, if I use as suggested "make html", an empty documentation is generated. So I continue the guide:

```
user@host:~/test/doc$ cd source/
user@host:~/test/doc/source$ cp index.rst ../dev/src/python-api/src/
user@host:~/test/doc/source$ cp conf.py ../dev/src/python-api/src/
user@host:~/test/doc/source$ sphynx-build -b html ../../dev/src/python-api
sphinx-build -b html ../../dev/src/python-api/src/ ../build
Sphinx v3.2.1 en cours d'exécution
WARNING: l'entrée html_static_path '_static' n'existe pas
construction en cours [mo]:cibles pour les fichiers po 0 qui sont périmées
construction [html]:cibles pour les fichiers sources 1 qui sont périmées
mise-à-jour de l'environnement :[nouvelle configuration] 1 ajouté, 0 modifié, 0 supprimé
lecture des sources... [100%] index                                                           
recherche des fichiers périmés... aucun résultat
environnement de sérialisation... fait
vérification de la cohérence... fait
document en préparation... fait
écriture... [100%] index                                                                      
generating indices...  genindexfait
writing additional pages...  searchfait
copie des fichiers statiques... ... fait
copying extra files... fait
dumping search index in English (code: en)... fait
dumping object inventory... fait
la compilation a réussi, 1 avertissement.

Les pages HTML sont dans ../build .
```

And again, the documentation html does not contains any code. I suppose the warning "WARNING: the entry html_static_path '_static' does not exists" is not important.

What did I miss ?

Comment: Your current project organization is suboptimal. Have a look at a [properly structured project and its documentation and tests](https://github.com/pylons/pyramid). Note that `src/myproject`, `tests`, and `docs` are all siblings at the root of the repository.

Comment: I'm working on a much more complex project, involving multiple modules, tools and languages. I cannot modify the project structure for now. Does this make sphinx unable to generate the documentation ?

Comment: I mean that you have the Sphinx configuration file `conf.py` and an `index.rst` in one directory and `docs` in another. That's... unusual. It is better to have all docs stuff in a docs directory and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't define which parts of your documentation from docstrings should be considered by Sphinx. For example, it is assumed that you have a file `./docs/sourc/index.rst` which contains something like:

```
.. automodule:: python.package.path.to.class
    :noindex:
```

There are actually a lot of different possibilities how to structure your documentation:
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

When you are done, just enter your doc folder and execute the following command:

```
sphinx-build -b html source build
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Using apidoc, I'm able to generate the documentation. :)